# getting error/not creating server files while doing ng add @nguniversal/express-engine@14.0.0 or @nguniversal/express-engine

Tags: javascript, angular, ng

here I'm trying to install ng add @nguniversal/express-engine@14.0.0 package to my angular project which is running on angular 14.0.0
But I'm getting error as Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"project":"app","appId":"serverApp","main":"main.server.ts","rootModuleFileName":"app.server.module.ts","rootModuleClassName":"AppServerModule","skipInstall":true}
Errors:

Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(appDir).
node version is,
20.11.1
And, If i use just ng add @nguniversal/express-engine, then I'll get error as NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID
my package.json is

```
{
"name": "learn",
"version": "0.0.1",
"author": "Ionic Framework",
"homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8100 --hmr -o",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint --fix",
"e2e": "ng e2e",
"dev": "concurrently --kill-others "npm run start" "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/styles.css -o ./src/theme/output.css --watch"",
"scully": "npx scully --",
"scully:serve": "npx scully serve --"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
"@angular/cdk": "14.0.4",
"@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/fire": "^7.4.1",
"@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^14.3.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.2.0",
"@ionic/angular": "^6.1.9",
"@ng-select/ng-select": "^6.1.0",
"@ngrx/effects": "^14.0.2",
"@ngrx/router-store": "^14.0.2",
"@ngrx/schematics": "^14.0.2",
"@ngrx/store": "^14.0.2",
"@ngrx/store-devtools": "^14.0.2",
"@nguniversal/express-engine": "^14.0.0",
"@scullyio/init": "^2.1.41",
"@scullyio/ng-lib": "^2.1.0",
"@scullyio/scully": "^2.1.0",
"@scullyio/scully-plugin-puppeteer": "^2.1.0",
"@sentry/angular": "^7.31.1",
"@sentry/tracing": "^7.31.1",
"@smartbear/browser-info": "^1.5.0",
"@supy-io/ngx-intercom": "^14.2.12",
"@trademe/ng-add-to-calendar": "^3.2.0",
"@types/googlemaps": "3.39.12",
"chart.js": "^3.9.1",
"date-fns": "^2.29.1",
"firebase": "^9.9.0",
"ng2-charts": "^4.0.0",
"ngx-cookie-service": "^14.0.1",
"ngx-youtube-player": "^12.0.2",
"rxjs": "~6.6.0",
"tinymce": "^6.1.2",
"tslib": "^2.2.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.0",
"@angular-eslint/builder": "~13.0.1",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~13.0.1",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~13.0.1",
"@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~13.0.1",
"@angular/cli": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/language-service": "^14.0.0",
"@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^6.0.0",
"@ngrx/eslint-plugin": "^14.0.2",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
"autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
"concurrently": "^7.2.2",
"eslint": "^7.6.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
"eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
"eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
"jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
"karma": "~6.3.2",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
"postcss": "^8.4.14",
"protractor": "~7.0.0",
"tailwindcss": "^3.1.6",
"ts-node": "~8.3.0",
"typescript": "~4.7.3"
},
"description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

my angular.json is

```
{
"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
"version": 1,
"newProjectRoot": "projects",
"defaultProject": "app",
"projects": {
"app": {
"root": "",
"sourceRoot": "src",
"projectType": "application",
"prefix": "app",
"schematics": {},
"architect": {
"build": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
"options": {
"allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
"@trademe/ng-add-to-calendar",
"@smartbear/browser-info",
"rudder-sdk-js"
],
"outputPath": "www",
"index": "src/index.html",
"main": "src/main.ts",
"polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
"tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
"assets": [
{
"glob": "/*",
"input": "src/assets",
"output": "assets"
},
{
"glob": "/.svg",
"input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
"output": "./svg"
}
],
"styles": [
"../new-theme/css/theme/variables.scss",
"src/global.scss",
"../new-theme/css/global.scss",
"node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css"
],
"scripts": [
"node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js"
],
"aot": false,
"vendorChunk": true,
"extractLicenses": false,
"buildOptimizer": false,
"sourceMap": true,
"optimization": false,
"namedChunks": true
},
"configurations": {
"production": {
"fileReplacements": [
{
"replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
"with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
],
"optimization": true,
"outputHashing": "all",
"sourceMap": false,
"namedChunks": false,
"aot": true,
"extractLicenses": true,
"vendorChunk": false,
"buildOptimizer": true,
"budgets": [
{
"type": "initial",
"maximumWarning": "2mb",
"maximumError": "5mb"
},
{
"type": "anyComponentStyle",
"maximumWarning": "3kb",
"maximumError": "4kb"
}
]
},
"ci": {
"progress": false
}
}
},
"serve": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
"options": {
"browserTarget": "app:build"
},
"configurations": {
"production": {
"browserTarget": "app:build:production"
},
"ci": {
"progress": false
}
}
},
"extract-i18n": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
"options": {
"browserTarget": "app:build"
}
},
"test": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
"options": {
"main": "src/test.ts",
"polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
"tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
"karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
"styles": [],
"scripts": [],
"assets": [
{
"glob": "favicon.ico",
"input": "src/",
"output": "/"
},
{
"glob": "**/",
"input": "src/assets",
"output": "/assets"
}
]
},
"configurations": {
"ci": {
"progress": false,
"watch": false
}
}
},
"lint": {
"builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
"options": {
"lintFilePatterns": [
"src//*.ts",
"src//*.html"
]
}
},
"e2e": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
"options": {
"protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
"devServerTarget": "app:serve"
},
"configurations": {
"production": {
"devServerTarget": "app:serve:production"
},
"ci": {
"devServerTarget": "app:serve:ci"
}
}
}
}
}
},
"cli": {
"schematicCollections": [
"@ionic/angular-toolkit"
],
"analytics": "ca60f425-cc60-42a1-9130-9adc7fdcb63e"
},
"schematics": {
"@ionic/angular-toolkit:component": {
"styleext": "scss"
},
"@ionic/angular-toolkit:page": {
"styleext": "scss"
}
}
}
```

errors are,
If i use "@nguniversal/express-engine@14.0.0", then getting error as
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"project":"app","appId":"serverApp","main":"main.server.ts","rootModuleFileName":"app.server.module.ts","rootModuleClassName":"AppServerModule","skipInstall":true}
Errors:

Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(appDir).

And if I use @nguniversal/express-engine then getting error as
NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID

my environment is,
[image]

Bottom line: package is getting installed but not creating the required files